# Configsets config commands are not executing sequencially cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This is metadata for cloudformationinit

```
{
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
      "configSets": {
        "setup": [
          "setup_docker",
          "setup_redis"
        ]
      },
      "setup_docker": {
        "commands": {
          "install_docker": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": ["", ["amazon-linux-extras install docker"]]
            }
          },
          "start_docker": {
            "command": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["service docker start"]] }
          },
          "start_on_restart": {
            "command": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["systemctl enable docker"]] }
          }
        }
      },
      "setup_redis": {
        "commands": {
          "install_redis": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": ["", ["amazon-linux-extras install redis6"]]
            }
          },
          "change_redis_6379_protected_mode": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "sed -i 's/protected-mode yes/protected-mode no/' /etc/redis/redis.conf"
                ]
              ]
            }
          },
          "change_redis_6379_daemonize": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                ["sed -i 's/daemonize no/daemonize yes/' /etc/redis/redis.conf"]
              ]
            }
          },
          "start_redis": {
            "command": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["systemctl start redis"]] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute this template, **setup_docker** commands got executed in order, first it will execute **install_docker**, then **start_docker**, then **start_on_restart** command, but **setup_redis** commands are not executing, first two commands got skipped, third command got executed and it throws an error **/etc/redis/redis.conf file not found**

[image: redis.conf file not found]

Why this is happening? commands are wrapped inside setup_redis object only and what is the solution for this?

Thanks in advance

**Update**
If I separate out the installation part of redis into separate config, it is working properly, does this mean command will not execute sequentially? Why commands are not executing sequentially?

```
{
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
      "configSets": {
        "setup": ["setup_redis", "modify_files"]
      },
      "setup_redis": {
        "commands": {
          "install_redis": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": ["", ["amazon-linux-extras install redis6"]]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "modify_files": {
        "commands": {
          "change_redis_6379_protected_mode": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "sed -i 's/protected-mode yes/protected-mode no/' /etc/redis/redis.conf"
                ]
              ]
            }
          },
          "change_redis_6379_daemonize": {
            "command": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                ["sed -i 's/daemonize no/daemonize yes/' /etc/redis/redis.conf"]
              ]
            }
          },
          "start_redis": {
            "command": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["systemctl start redis"]] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": {
      "Ref": "AMI"
    },
    "KeyName": {
      "Ref": "Key"
    },
    "InstanceType": {
      "Ref": "InstanceTypeParameter"
    },
    "SubnetId": {
      "Ref": "SubnetIdParameter"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIds": {
      "Ref": "SecurityGroupIdsParameter"
    },
    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.57",
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "#!/bin/bash -xe",
            "\n",
            "yum update -y",
            "\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v",
            " --stack ",
            { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
            " --resource DevInstance",
            " --configsets setup",
            " --region ",
            { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
            "\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $?",
            " --stack ",
            { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
            " --resource DevInstance",
            " --region ",
            { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
            "\n"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `amazon-linux-extras install redis6` is failing; does that command work if you run it manually?

Comment: @Paolo yeah I tried it manually, it is working, I tried `sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6` and if it ran and failed, it should appear in log right? confused why it is not shown in log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands are processed in alphabetical order by name. So in your original configuration, they were going to be executed in this order:

1. change_redis_6379_daemonize
2. change_redis_6379_protected_mode
3. install_redis
4. start_redis

Separating out the installation part to make it execute first is the correct solution.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands